# displaying Object arrays only shows memory locations

Tags: java, arrays, object, contacts, println

So I'm working on a little contact organizer and what it does is store different contacts( telephone, email and postal) and display them or erase them and what not. So far, the program can create contacts, right now i'm trying to display them. But it only shows the memory locations and not the actual Object. The elements are Objects, so is there a special way to SOP Object arrays?

Also,  i have seperate classes for each type of Contact with their set of mutators, accessors and constructor(Telephone class, Email class and Postal class. Contact is the Interface).

My code for the program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;

/**
 * Contact program.
 * 
 * @author Janarthanan Manoharan 
 * @version 1.0 2013-11-24
 */
public class ContactOrganizer
{
    // class constants 
    private static final String C = "[C]reate contact";
    private static final String D = "[D]isplay contacts";
    private static final String E = "[E]rase contact";
    private static final String F = "[F]ind contact";
    private static final String H = "[H]elp";
    private static final String Q = "[Q]uit";

    // other constants    
    private static final String CREATE_CONTACT = "C";
    private static final String DISPLAY_CONTACT = "D";
    private static final String ERASE_CONTACT = "E";
    private static final String FIND_CONTACT = "F";
    private static final String HELP = "H";
    private static final String QUIT = "Q";

    private static final String one = "telephone";
    private static final String two = "email";
    private static final String three = "postal";

    private static final int CONTACT_LIMIT = 1000;
    private static final int PHONE_NUMBER_LIMIT = 10; 

    private static Contact[] contactArray = new Contact[CONTACT_LIMIT];
    private static int contactCounter = 0;
    private static BufferedReader input;    

    /**
     * Contact program.
     * 
     * @param arguments not used
     */
    public static void main(String[] argument)
    {
        String choice  = "";
        String command = "";

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("CONTACT ORGANIZER");
        System.out.println("\n" + C);
        System.out.println(D);
        System.out.println(E);
        System.out.println(F);
        System.out.println(H);
        System.out.println(Q);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("\nEnter a command, master: ");
            try
            {
                command = input.readLine();

                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase(CREATE_CONTACT))
                {
                    System.out.println("Telephone, Email, Postal? ");
                    choice = input.readLine();

                    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(one))
                    {
                        createTelephone();
                    }
                    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(two))
                    {
                        createEmail();
                    }
                    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(three))
                    {
                        createPostal();
                    }

                }

                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase(DISPLAY_CONTACT))
                {
                    displayContacts(contactArray);
                }
                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase(HELP))
                {
                    System.out.println("CONTACTS");
                    System.out.println("\n" + C);
                    System.out.println(D);
                    System.out.println(E);
                    System.out.println(F);
                    System.out.println(H);
                    System.out.println(Q);
                } // end of if (command.equalsIgnoreCase(HELP))

                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase(QUIT))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nO");
                    System.out.println(" F");
                    System.out.println("  F");
                    System.out.println("   !");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
            }
        }
        while(!command.equalsIgnoreCase(null));
    }

    private static void createTelephone()
    {
        long customer = 0;
        int areaCode = 0;
        int exchange = 0;
        boolean isNumberValid = false;
        int length = 0;
        int number = 0;
        //         int phoneNumber = 0;
        int type = 0; 

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter customer ID: ");
            customer = Long.parseLong(input.readLine());

            do
            {
                System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
                long phoneNumber = Long.parseLong(input.readLine());

                if (Long.toString(phoneNumber).length() == PHONE_NUMBER_LIMIT)
                {
                    isNumberValid = true;
                    areaCode = Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(phoneNumber).substring(0,3));
                    exchange = Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(phoneNumber).substring(3,6));
                    number = Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(phoneNumber).substring(6));
                } // end of if (Long.toString(phoneNumber).length() == PHONE_NUMBER_LIMIT)
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("INVALID NUMBER, TRY AGAIN");
                }
            }
            while(!isNumberValid);

            System.out.println("Home: 10, Work: 20, Other: 30");
            System.out.println("Enter type: ");
            type = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

            contactArray[contactCounter]  = new TelephoneContact(customer, areaCode, exchange, number, type);

            contactCounter++;

            System.out.println("CONTACT CREATED!");
            System.out.println(areaCode + "" + exchange + "" + number);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
        } // end of try block
    } // end of createTelephone()

    private static void createEmail()
    {
        long customer = 0;
        String domain = "";
        String user = "";
        int type = 0;

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter customer ID: ");
            customer = Long.parseLong(input.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter username: ");
            user = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter domain: ");
            domain = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter type: ");
            type = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

            contactArray[contactCounter]  = new EmailContact(customer, user, domain, type);

            contactCounter++;

            System.out.println("CONTACT CREATED!");           
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
        } // end of try block
    } // end of createEmail()

    private static void createPostal()
    {
        long customer = 0;
        String address = "";
        String postalCode = "";
        int type = 0;

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter customer ID: ");
            customer = Long.parseLong(input.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter address: ");
            address = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter postal code: ");
            postalCode = input.readLine();

            System.out.println("Enter type: ");
            type = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

            contactArray[contactCounter]  = new EmailContact(customer, address, postalCode, type);

            contactCounter++;

            System.out.println("CONTACT CREATED!");           
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU DONE MESSED UP AARON!");
        } // end of try block
    } // end of createPostal()

    private static void displayContacts(Contact[] contactArray)
    {
        Contact[] telephoneArray = new Contact[CONTACT_LIMIT];
        Contact[] emailArray = new Contact[CONTACT_LIMIT];
        Contact[] postalArray = new Contact[CONTACT_LIMIT];

        //System.out.println("\nTELEPHONE CONTACTS");
        for (int i = 0; i < contactArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (contactArray[i] != null)
            {
                System.out.println(contactArray[i]);
            }

        }
    }

} // end of class ContactProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

For intelligible output when you print out an object, you need to override [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) on your class, as described in ["Object as a Superclass"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html). For example:

```
public class Contact {
    // some fields
    // some accessors

    public String toString() {
        return "this will be printed";
    }
}
```

Note that `toString()` should almost always be used strictly for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you should override the `toString()` in the EmailContact` class, since that's the type of the array, you want to print out. For example:

```
class EmailContact{
    String customer;
    String address;
    String postalCode;
    String type;

    public EmailContact(String customer, String address, 
                        String postalCode, String type) {

        this.customer = customer;
        this.address = address;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.type = type;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Customer: " + customer +
               "\nAddress: " + address +
               "\nPostal Code: " + postalCode +
               "\nType: " + type;         
    }
}
```

Or override the `toString()` in the `Contact` class. Whichever you want to format the printing of. Both if necessary

**Edit: with OP question in comment**

**Question:** What exactly does the @Override do because i tried it on the toDisplayString() in the Telephone, Email and Postal class and it still displayed on the memory locations.

**Answer:**  `@Override` overrides the `toString()` that is inherited from the `Object` class. For example if you want to print `System.out.println(someEmailContactObject);`, it will use the `Object#toString` method and print the memory location, unless you override it with the way you want it printed.

If you want to use your `toDisplayString()`, then you have to do this `System.out.println(someEmialContactObject.toDisplayString());`.

When you override, you have to override with the exact method signature

```
@Override
public String toString(){

}
```

This, below, does not override anything

```
@Override 
public String toDisplayString(){
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the @Override do because i tried it on the toDisplayString() in the Telephone, Email and Postal class and it still displayed on the memory locations.